# Function not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Why doesn't this work in Firefox?

```html
<li class="selected"><a onclick="tabbing(this, p1)" href="javascript:void(0)">ABC</a></li>
<li><a onclick="tabbing(this, p2)" href="javascript:void(0)">XYZ</a></li>

<div id="p1"></div>
<div id="p2"></div>
```

```js
function tabbing(ex,id){ 
    alert(ex)    
}
```

p1 and p2 are just containers for my AJAX result.

**Edit**: I found the solution. Instead of passing just the id name, I passed this line as the parameter:

```js
document.getElementById('p1')
```

So it's like this now:

```js
tabbing(this, document.getElementById('p1'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that `p1` and `p2` are not defined.  In order to use them in a statement like this: `tabbing(this, p2)`, the variable `p2` must be defined.

Do you mean for `p1` and `p2` to be passed as variables or do you mean to pass them as strings?

If you intend for `p1` and `p2` to be strings, then you should pass them like this:

```
<li class="selected">
    <a onclick="tabbing(this, 'p1')" href="javascript:void(0)">ABC</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a onclick="tabbing(this, 'p2')" href="javascript:void(0)">XYZ</a>
</li>
```

Comment: They're not used by the function though. Wouldn't they just have the value `undefined`?

Comment: If you accessed them as `window.p1` they would have a value of `undefined`, but accessing them as just `p1` will cause a script error if they are not defined.  I verified that in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Xm9HY/

Comment: i forgot to include the two elements, p1 and p2, uhmm they're elements (containers).. they're not strings..

Comment: @JadeBaribar - as you've now updated your HTML to show the p1 and p2 objects, those are just id strings.  You should either pass them as the id (a string) or you should retrieve the DOM object with document.getElementById('p1') and pass the object.  It depends upon how you want to use the argument in your function (which you do not show).

Comment: BTW, silly IE actually allows that non-sense..  Which is why it doesn't work in Mozilla..

Comment: @jfriend00 showing the whole code or not, this just doesn't work in mozilla.. if im going to do this in chrome, it would run. and btw, can you explain to me this "p1 and p2 are just id strings".. i dont quite get it. the one said earlier.. if you don't mind. im quite dumb XD

Comment: @JadeBaribar - when you have this HTML `<div id="p1"></div>`, p1 is just a string id that can be used to reference that object.  If you want to get the actual DOM object in javascript, you use `var obj = document.getElementById("p1");`.  IE may allow you to use `p1` and `p2` directly as variables, but that is not a good cross browser way to write javascript.  You should fetch the DOM object with `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 but my question is not something like that. is there anyway for this code to work in mozilla? the passing of parameters?